# jquery fileupload parserror

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using a jquery fileupload to make a gallery images from a website, but in some browsers I can upload the image normally but in another this code does not works and return for me in console the erro "parseerror", Anybody can help me ?

function uploadGaleriaEstabelecimento(){

```
var url = window.location.hostname === 'example.com' ? 'http://www.example.com/control/php/request/ajax.files.estabelecimento.php' : '';

console.log(url);

$('#fileupload').fileupload({

    url: url,

    dataType: 'json',

    error: function (error, req) {

        console.log(error);
        console.log(req);

        $('.alert-galeria-erro').slideDown();
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.alert-galeria-erro').slideUp() }, 7000);
    },

    done: function (e, data) {

        $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {

                $.ajax({

                url : URL_BASE + "php/request/ajax.files.estabelecimento.php",

                data: {register:"1",estabelecimento:$("#estabelecimento").val(), file:file.name},

                type: "POST",

                dataType:"json",

                success : function (response){

                    console.log(response.id);

                    $(".lista-files").append("<li id='imagem-"+response.id+"'><img src='images/estabelecimento/" + file.name + "' height='200' ><form class='ordem'><input type='text' name='ordem' value='0' size='2'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='"+response.id+"'><input type='submit' value='Salvar' class='ls-btn'><button data-ls-module='modal' data-id='"+response.id+"' data-target='#apagar-modal' class='apagar-modal ls-btn-danger'>Apagar</button></form></li>");

                    }

                });
        });
    },

    progressall: function (e, data) {

        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);

        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(

            'width',

            progress + '%'

        );
    }

}).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)

    .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
```

}

Comment: What browser, and what is the error returned in the console?

Comment: I tested in firefox and chrome, the error return for me is parserror